# Using Java Stream to instantiate difrent number of new objects with index and specific Enum value

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to create mock data for my tests. I need to generate a list of storage rooms with different size and index.

Here is the StorageRoom entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table(name = "storage_rooms")
public class StorageRoom {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private Size size;
    private boolean reserved;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime startDate;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime endDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Warehouse warehouse;
}
```

Here is the Size enum:

```
    @Getter
    public enum Size {
    TELEPHONE_BOX(10),
    LARGE_WALK_IN_WARDROBE(20),
    GARDEN_SHED(30),
    LARGE_GARDEN_SHED(40),
    LUTON_VAN(75),
    LARGE_SINGLE_GARAGE(125),
    ONE_AND_HALF_GARAGES(150),
    STANDARD_DOUBLE_GARAGE(200),
    LARGE_DOUBLE_GARAGE(250),
    THREE_SINGLE_GARAGES(300),
    TWO_DOUBLE_GARAGES(400),
    TWO_SHIPPING_CONTAINERS(500);

    private int size;

    Size(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
}
```

I created a method for generating a list of storage rooms, which looks like that:

```
    static List<StorageRoom> createStorageRoomsList() {
    List<StorageRoom> list = new ArrayList<>();
    var index = 100L;

    for (var i = 0; i < Size.values().length; i++) {
        var temp = i;
        while (temp >= 0) {
            list.add(StorageRoom.builder()
                    .id(index++)
                    .size(Size.values()[i])
                    .reserved(false)
                    .build());
            temp--;
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Is it possible to do exactly the same list generation but with Streams?

So far by using streams I created a method like that:

```
    static List<StorageRoom> createStorageRoomsListStream() {
    AtomicLong index = new AtomicLong(100L);
    return Arrays.stream(Size.values())
            .map(size -> StorageRoom.builder()
                    .id(index.getAndIncrement())
                    .size(size)
                    .build())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The problem is that this method creates 1 instance for each size. How can I make it work if I want to have a different number of instances for each size?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `IntStream` may be used to define a number of the values to be created, then a `flatMap` should be applied:

```java
static List<StorageRoom> createStorageRoomsListStream() {
    AtomicLong index = new AtomicLong(100L);
    AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(1);
    return Arrays.stream(Size.values())
            .flatMap(size -> IntStream.range(0, count.getAndIncrement())
                    .mapToObj(i -> StorageRoom.builder()
                        .id(index.getAndIncrement())
                        .size(size)
                        .build()
                    )
            )
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Instead of `count` a random value may be applied if needed.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create stream by concatenating multiple streams of `Size.values()` something like below,

`Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(Size.values()),Arrays.stream(Size.values()))`
You can provide as many values you want. This will create same number of instances for each Size.